# Reinstall development stack

Tags: ios, xcode, development-environment, keychain

I need to relocate my iPhone development stack to a different machine. What do I need to do in preparation and are there any gotchas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to export and transport your private keys, used for signing, from Keychain Access.

See page 10 in the "Program Portal User Guide" available from the "Program Portal", where you manage your certificates at apple.com

Comment: If you want to move your entire keychain over, you can export it via Keychain Access.  That will move al your saved passwords and such over too.